# How to dereference a function pointer and read as data under MSVC++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly

Below is my attempt to read the machine code pointed to by a function pointer and print it. Currently, the data being printed is not the same as the code that is generated... I've checked the values of the pointers created in the produced executable and listed by the disassembler (there is a difference between code/debugger) but don't see anything too troubling, or understand how I might fix the problem.

```
void dummy();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("\nReading dummy...\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        printf("%.2X ", ((char *)((void *)dummy))[i]);
    puts("");

    dummy();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void __declspec(naked) dummy()
{
    __asm
    {
        nop;
        nop;
        nop;
        nop;

        ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what the calls to `printf()` end up printing?

Comment: What do you expect, what do you get, and what does the debugger show when you use the memory dump window on your function address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two common mistakes to make here.  First off, cast to `unsigned char*` instead of char*.  Next, and the important one, Project + Properties, Linker, General and turn off Incremental Linking.

With incremental linking enabled, a function address actually points to a little stub that contains nothing but a JMP to the real function.  Which allows the linker to replace old code with new code without having to rebuild the entire executable image.  Your code is reading that stub instead of the real function when incremental linking is enabled.  Proper output:

```
Reading dummy...
90 90 90 90 C3 //... rest is random
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I should have looked more closely at the code that was being dumped - I figured it was linker tomfoolery, but I wasn't sure what. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess, it printed this:

```
FFFFFF90 FFFFFF90 FFFFFF90 FFFFFF90 FFFFFFC3
```

Try using the `hh` length modifier with printf:

```
printf("%02hhX ", ((char *)((void *)dummy))[i]);
```

Output:

```
90 90 90 90 C3
```

The `X` specifier, by itself, prints the value as an `unsigned int` but you pass in a `char` promoted to `signed int`.  The `hh` modifier changes it to `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
printf("%.2X ", ((char *)((void *)dummy))[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%.2X ", ((unsigned char *)dummy)[i]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintHex(const char* input, const int len)
{
     char * tmp=new char[len*3+1];
     for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
          sprintf(tmp+i*3,"%02x ",*(input+i)&0xFF);

     printf("%s\n",tmp);
};
```

Comment: -1, This would give the same results as OP's code, or worse. It also incorrectly uses signed `char`, except here it would actually cause a buffer overflow. And what's the point of allocating the buffer, when you can just output the values directly?